# transforming DataFrame shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to transfrom my DataFrame in which I have rows from 2 years and I want to compare two years dates values I have df like below.

```
         Date            item        group       amount
0.       1/2/2019        car         1           110000
1.       20/2/2019       bat         2           2000
2.       10/2/2019       Ring        3           3880
3.       15/2/2019       machine     4           4500
4.       27/2/2019       Radio       5           2400
5.       21/2/2019        car         1           45000
0.       1/2/2020        car         1           130000
1.       20/2/2020       bat         2           2090
2.       10/2/2020       Ring        3           3200
3.       15/2/2020       machine     4           6500
4.       27/2/2020       Radio       5           9900
5.       21/2/2020        car         1           54280
```

I want this to transform into dataframe in which item with group that should shows in 2019 column total amounts of each item in 2019 and in 2020 column total amounts of each item in 2020.

```
       item     group      2019         2020
0.    car        1         155000       184280
1.    bat        2         2000         2090
2.    Ring       3         3880         3200
3.    Machine    4         4500         6500
4.    Radio      5         2400         9900
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.year
pdf = pd.pivot_table(df, values='amount', index=['item', 'group'], columns=['Year'], 
                     aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index(drop=False).sort_values(['group'])
print(pdf)

Year     item  group    2019    2020
3         car      1  155000  184280
2         bat      2    2000    2090
1        Ring      3    3880    3200
4     machine      4    4500    6500
0       Radio      5    2400    9900
```

[Working example](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/5467ffdf.py)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
In [2997]: df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
In [3036]: x = pd.crosstab(index=[df.item, df.group], columns=df.Date.dt.year, values=df.amount, aggfunc='sum').reset_index().sort_values('group')

In [3037]: x
Out[3037]: 
Date     item  group    2019    2020
3         car      1  155000  184280
2         bat      2    2000    2090
1        Ring      3    3880    3200
4     machine      4    4500    6500
0       Radio      5    2400    9900
```

**OR:**

Use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [2997]: df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

In [3024]: x = df.pivot_table(index=['item', 'group'], columns=df.Date.dt.year, values='amount', aggfunc='sum').reset_index().sort_values('group')

In [3025]: x
Out[3025]: 
Date     item  group    2019    2020
3         car      1  155000  184280
2         bat      2    2000    2090
1        Ring      3    3880    3200
4     machine      4    4500    6500
0       Radio      5    2400    9900
```

Answer (score 1):

A groupby, coupled with unstack could do the trick :

```
(df.assign(Date=df.Date.dt.year)
   .groupby(["Date", "item", "group"])
   .amount
   .sum()
   .unstack("Date")
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
 )

    
    item    group   2019    2020
0   Radio   5       2400    9900
1   Ring    3       3880    3200
2   bat     2       2000    2090
3   car     1       155000  184280
4   machine 4       4500    6500
```

Manually controlling your aggregations can offer some speed advantages over pivot_table or crosstab, which is based on pivot_table. As, always, tests are a sure way to verify speed; only if you need the speed.

Comment: Its great. can you tell me why here rename_axis(columns=None) used...?

Comment: To get rid of the columns name. If you stop at the rest index you will see a Date name